# multiview iPhone application

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, multiview

I am trying to build an application that upon opening you will see a table view, with several elements. After you click on an element you will be taken to a new view which is a tab bar controller. I have created a navigation controller as my root view controller and what I am trying to figure out is do I need to pass off the root view controller's function from the navigation controller element to the tab bar controller? And then the tab bar controller does the work? I have been reading

Beginning IPhone 4 Development: Exploring the IOS SDK [Book] by David Mark, Jack Nutting, Jeff LaMarche

Chapter 7 gives a good example of how to use a tab bar controller but how can I pass the functions of the navigation controller to the tab bar controller that I am using?

Comment: Your tab bar controller should hold navigation controllers. Maybe it is easier to put your table view into the tab bar controller aswell but hide the tab bar when at the table view then show the tab bar when a row is tapped?

Comment: Simon, thank you. That is an interesting way to look at it. So my next question would be, the tab bar that is shown (after the table item is selected) depends on the specific item pressed. Doing it your way, will the application be able to load different data or is it already preloaded? Do you know of any examples that may have something like this?

Comment: So the tab bar should show different tabs (or atleast the tabs should bring different views) depending on which row was selected in the table view? Honestly, I don't know. I would guess it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use navigation controller at root and after that tab bar controller as following way:-

this one is yr application delegate's .h file:-

```
@interface NavTabDemoAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
   IBOutlet  UINavigationController *navController;
    IBOutlet UITabBarController *TabBar;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet  UINavigationController *navController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *TabBar;
```

this one is yr app delegate's .m file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self.window addSubview:navController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

drag and drop navigation controller and tab bar controller from library to main window.xib and set outlets to application delegates

In yr tableview view controller's .h file, create object of yr delegate as follows

```
NavTabDemoAppDelegate *appdelegate;
```

in .m file of yr tableview controller at viewdidload

```
appdelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

just write this at tableview view controller's DidSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:appdelegate.TabBar animated:YES];
```

done!